# Kivy running but no window appears

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, cs50

So I am a beginner and am using Kivy for the first time. I am using visual studio code as an editor. I am also using wsl. Inside it, I installed Kivy using

```
pip install kivy[full]
```

I also set up a virtual environment as per the guide on the website.

and I wrote this code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class NeuralRandom(App):

    def build(self):
        return Label(text="NeuralRandom")
    
neuralRandom = NeuralRandom()
neuralRandom.run()
```

Instead of showing an error or working it just doesn't show the output window when I execute python3 app.py where app.py is the name of the python file. This is the output I am getting so far:-

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/jay_shah3616/.kivy/logs/kivy_23-05-30_20.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.2.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/home/jay_shah3616/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.10.6 (main, Mar 10 2023, 10:55:28) [GCC 11.3.0]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/usr/bin/python3"
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 190 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [ImageLoaderFFPy] Using ffpyplayer 4.5.0
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_ffpyplayer 
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.5 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 22.2.5'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Mesa/X.org'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'llvmpipe (LLVM 15.0.6, 256 bits)'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 5
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.50'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
```

I have waited for a few minutes but the program seems to be stuck at this point and I am not sure what is wrong. Since it doesn't show any errors I think the only problem is that it isn't showing me the app window. I tried searching for a solution online but found nothing. Any help will be greatly appreciated